# Font X is not available to the JVM

Tags: jasper-reports

I am setting up a microservice and in local tests I do not get this type of source error, I tried to inject libraries but the error persists, the call with postman returns the following message, some solution? 
I'm using jasper's report.

```
{

 "timestamp": "2018-05-31T12:38:44.488+0000",
 "status": 500,
 "error": "Internal Server Error",
 "message": "Font \"Calibri\" is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details.",
"path": "/report"

}
```

Comment: The remote server doesn't have Calibri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a *Calibri* font on your JasperReports server instance. You need to a generate font extension file using *Calibri.ttf* (font file, download it from internet) with iReports/ Jasper Studio and add it as jar to Jasperserver's lib folder to make it available across your application.

There is a complete section dedicated on working with font extension on jasper community, have a look:
 [working-font-extensions](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v630/working-font-extensions)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have managed to export the font in a jar but I have doubts about how to integrate it into the project, I am using spring boot.

Comment: @dani, you should add this jar into your project's classpath